# Is there any way to know in how many hours the alarm will go off?

Tags: iphone, ios, clock, alarm

I need to know in how much time exactly the alarm will go off.

The information it very important since when I go to bed I plan how many hours of sleep do I get and which alarm should I activate.

When I searched, it seems that older version of iOS used to have this feature, but I cannot find it in IOS 12.

Comment: Are you asking how long the alarm will sound if not shut off (which is what your first sentence says) or the time remaining until the alarm goes off (which is what your second sentence says)?

Comment: @fsb - I'm not seeing any conflict in the two sentences. I think the OP's confusion is that a *timer* will show time remaining on the lock screen, but an *alarm* will not.

Comment: @Tetsujin maybe it's the way we're both reading the question, I don't know.  The fact that we both get different ideas of what's being asked is, I believe, enough that the OP should should try to make a clarifying edit (before the 'unclear' flags start).

Comment: @Tetsujin, the lock screen shows the time of the alarm in the lock screen, however, I am not able to see the time remaining. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @fsb, I updated the title. Does it make sense now?

Comment: It puzzles me that this was part of the older version of IOS. What it is misisng or so hard to find for me?

Comment: I've never seen the time of an alarm in the lock screen, the only indication is the little alarm clock icon in the top bar. I've only ever seen the remaining time in a timer [& that's only since maybe iOS 10]

Comment: @Tetsujin, How do you get the remaining time oon the lcok screen? Any chnace you have a screenshot, or an image on the internet?

Comment: "Hey Siri. Set Timer for 3 minutes" "OK, your timer is set" Switch off, hold up phone to see lock screen. Countdown is under the main clock.

Comment: pic posted - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciknI.jpg timer under main clock

Comment: Thanks for the vain and digressing efforts, @Tetsujin. There was no mention and interest of timer by OP. His/her English is weak and you made no efforts to compensate for that. Also, if one swipes towards right from home screen or "lit up locked screen", one can see the first alarm's time but still not the remaining time, in the widget section. Widgets can be edited by going to the bottom and tapping the "Edit" button.
Also, one can use bedtime for seeing the remaining time but only in the alarm app.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii, I am asking specifically about alarm. Someone misunderestood and explain about timer. What does it have to do with my English weakness?

Comment: @Tetsujin, thank you for help. Please note that I am looking for the remaining time to Alarm. our screenshot shoes timer.

Comment: @AllanXu  you weren’t clear enough in removing the ambiguity in the comments. Does bedtime does what you need ?

Comment: @Tetsujin you started the confusion by mentioning the lock screen and timer both in your initial comment.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii, yes, bedtime does what I need. Thank you. Still it is strange that Apple decided to remove the feature. Also I wanted to thank Tetsujin for his time and help.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii, Tetsujin replied to my older version of question that was not clear enough.